# Hierarchical XML to one flat DataTable C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dataset

I am trying to figure out the best way to flatten a hierarchical xml file into a flattened dataset table. I am writing this in C# and prefer to use built-in and elegant .net functionality. Sorry for the formatting - not sure why its turning out so weird.

```
var dataset = new DataSet();
dataset.ReadXml(@"xmlfile.xml"); //reading in the hierarchical xml
//do something here
data.WriteXml(@"flatdatasetfile.xml"); //write out the flat dataset here
```

Here is the xml I have:

```
<xml>
<customers>
 <customer_details>
  <customer>1</customer>
  <name>Smith</name>
 </customer_details>
    <items>
     <item_details>
      <item>1</item>
      <description>blah</description>
     </item_details>
     <item_details>
      <item>2</item>
      <description>blah2</description>
     </item_details>
    </items>
 <customer_details>
  <customer>2</customer>
  <name>Jones</name>
 </customer_details>
    <items>
     <item_details>
      <item>1</item>
      <description>blah</description>
     </item_details>
     <item_details>
      <item>3</item>
      <description>blah3</description>
     </item_details>
    </items>
</customers>
</xml>
```

Expected result:

```
<dataset>
  <customer_item>
    <customer>1</customer>
    <name>Smith</name>
    <item>1</item>
    <description>blah</description>
  </customer_item>
  <customer_item>
    <customer>1</customer>
    <name>Smith</name>
    <item>2</item>
    <description>blah2</description>
  </customer_item>
  <customer_item>
    <customer>2</customer>
    <name>Jones</name>
    <item>1</item>
    <description>blah</description>
  </customer_item>
  <customer_item>
    <customer>2</customer>
    <name>Jones</name>
    <item>3</item>
    <description>blah3</description>
  </customer_item>
</dataset>
```

Comment: So what exactly is the issue ?

Comment: Loading that xml file into a dataset will create several tables - one for each level of the hierarchy. I need it to load one table where the parent level (customer_details) will get a row for each one of its child item_details. Each row will contain the customer data and the item data.

Comment: `I am writing this in C#` I don't see any c# code...

Comment: var dataset = new DataSet();

Comment: You cannot do that with purely "out of the box" code. You will need to override the Deserialize method of the DataSet to be able to load the flattened Xml in the way you want.